# Add more columns and add to basket to the grid in grouped products Magento 2

Tags: catalog, custom-attributes, grouped-products, magento2.2.4

I'm trying to add more columns, with custom attributes into the frontend product grid in Magento 2.2.4

I've overridden

vendor/magento/module-grouped-product/Block/Product/View/Type/grouped.phtml

into my local module and I can get text to appear in the grid but not custom attributes.

I'm obviously missing something obvious but not sure what.

My custom product attributes consist of 3 types:
text, dropdown and multiselect
but I can't even get the text one to show up

I've also tried adding in individual row "Add To Basket" buttons and they appear but don't do anything when clicked.

I've spent days searching and can only find answers for M1.

This is an example from a website that does it quite well, not sure what engine they use

[image]

Would appreciate your help everyone

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/GroupedProduct/Model/Product/Type/Grouped.php#L211

You can add your custom attributes by overriding that method.

Comment: Thanks.

That works on core attributes like 'sku' but doesn't add custom attributes.

I can't get it to show any attribute I've added even though they show in the attribute block on the product page.

Any other ideas, would really appreciate it.